# How to determine if a SQL query is a SELECT?

Tags: sql, validation, select

Morning SO.

**EDIT**

I would like to do some validation on sql queries to verify that this query is a SELECT and not an UPDATE or a DELETE or an INSERT or any sql weird statement.

I know that the easiest way is to match "^SELECT" BUT :

- a query can start with "(" like

  (SELECT * FROM blah WHERE id > 1 LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT * ...)
- a query can start with " WITH RECURSIVE "

  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT * FROM blah)

I Would like to determine if a SQL query is a SELECT.
Well I don't know if there is some weird queries I have to know before writing a regexp.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I want to check if it's a PURE Select query :)

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you trying to parse? Different vendors offer different syntax and options, though your example appears to be a CTE on SQL Server.

Comment: seems it's not SQL Server specific : http://www.davidcramer.net/code/django/6939/scaling-threaded-comments-on-django-at-disqus.html

Comment: Why would you need this? This seems like something that may be best handled by database permissions. SQL Server 2008 has composable DML that allows you to select from an Update statement for example. You won't be able to come up with a single Regex for this task.

Comment: I would like to improve django's Manager.raw() validation

Comment: If this is something you want to do for security: please don't. You will simply fail miserably, because hackers will find ways to execute queries that you think are okay to execute.

Comment: this method is used to validate if this kind of queries can be executed.It's like a "feature check". security checks are made in another level. thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to handle this is with permissions - you grant the user running the query db_reader permissions in sql server, but not db_writer or anything else.  Then you handle the error/exception if the query fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make update statemtents that run their own SELECTs inside to find out data to update, or many other ways to embed statements into eachother... Assuming you don't use "SELECT" as data or field-names just run a regex for `/\bselect\b/i` otherwise you will need a full blown parser.

**Edit:** also: `/\b(insert|update)\b/i` invert that to make sure there are none of them in it.

Comment: No, this request must be a pure SELECT. I mean it CAN'T be an update, an insert or whatelse.

Comment: Well you can just as easily add an insert update or whatelse query inside a select so... Just run `/\b(insert|update)\b/i` with extra options and invert the output.

Comment: The following is technically allowed in SQL Server `create table [ insert ] ([ update ] int); insert into  [ insert ] values (1); select [ update ] from [ insert ]`

Answer (score -3):

if query starts by word "select" (case insensitive) then it's a select query

Comment: No, SELECT can starts with "(SELECT)" as I said. I would like to know if there are some more possibilities.